# Pgfplot Externalize & Trim Axes

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external

I've recently run into a pickle. I like to use pgfplots to create figures in my reports. Occasionally I have enough figures that I'd like to use the **externalize** option of pgfplots. This means the figure gets created as a standalone PDF (but it inherits all the settings from the master tex file) that I can then import as a PDF into the final file. It avoids having to wait for the compiler to create each figure each time the document is compiled.

However, I also like to use the `trim axis left` and `right`. It seems I cannot combine the use of externalize along with the trim axis options.

Here is a simplified example. Let's say I have a paper and I want to include a plot of sin(x) and cos(x). I also want to use the externalize option of pgfplots so I can compile the plots separately from the rest of the paper. I am using the subfiles package so that the tex files inherit all the settings and characteristics of my master file.

```
\documentclass[../../TeX/Project1.tex]{subfiles}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = My X Axis,
        ylabel = My Y Axis
      ]
        \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[../../TeX/Project1.tex]{subfiles}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = My X Axis,
        ylabel = My Y Axis
      ]
        \addplot {cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And from the main tex file:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../Figures/SineFigTest/SineFig-figure0.pdf}
      \captionof{figure}{My First Figure Caption}
      \label{P1:SinPlot}
  \end{minipage}\hspace{0.60in}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../Figures/CosFigTest/CosFig-figure0.pdf}
      \captionof{figure}{My Second Figure Caption}
      \label{P1:CosPlot}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

I'd like to include these plots side-by-side in the paper and I want them to be centered based on the sides of the plots **not** including the y-axis labels. The only way I can tell to accomplish this is to compile the figures as part of the paper itself (i.e. avoid using externalize) and using the `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` options of `tikzpicture`.

My question is whether or not it is possible to externalize the plots and still achieve the effect of the `trim axis` options?

If you have any other suggestions or ideas more generally based on the snippets I've included above on how to improve my tex-ing I'd love to know.

Hopefully this makes my questions more clear. If not please let me know and perhaps I will delete and re-think on how to submit this.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I understand your question right, and because you didn't get an answer so far, I guess I am not the only one. Could you add a sketch or some screenshots to the question? I guess this will help a lot to clarify what you want. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated the question with an example.